# Audio-in live net streaming in Win8.1 laptop fails

Tags: audio, streaming

I cannot get any streamed / live sounds from eg BBC radios(any) / sports.
It is OK on another PC: win7/64 on the same ISP, ethernet cable router shared, at the same time, in the same location.

ISP download speeds are erratic but mostly above 6mbs (topped @ 20). A total failure from that is very unlikely to totally block.

It was somewhat erratic with Win8.0 (last autumn; I blamed it on the power-lined ethernet remote connection and long line losses involved).

Now:
BBC iPlayer (archive) downloads and plays sound normally, radio or TV.

BBC iPlayer (listen live) fails: msg. 'stream broken' or 'equipment mismatch' <<<<<<<

pings (many, various: no losses)

Win Media Player is default on both 8.1 and 7/64

All W8.1 internal settings seem configured correctly in Sounds & Devices

(Devices: Sound: uninstalled and reinstalled, just in case.

I tested a music CD output etc = working: speakers and 'phones).

Comment: Is it ONLY the BBC iPlayer that fails to stream, or are there other examples you've found?  Assuming you used IE to test; did you try it in a different browser?

Comment: It is for my wife's (W8.1) laptop, Chrome default (both).

I have now tested on some alternative streams, direct from radioplayer.co.uk (which BBC uses/links to), with both PCs cabled on the same router, at the same time.(Evening pm session)

Both are independently receiving erratically and unreliably, with non- and BBC channels.
I will run a few more sessions.

I now suspect ISP download speeds / bandwidths (nominal max,is 20bmps but is often far lower and in particular erratic). 

Evidence continues to be collected for discussion with my ISP!   

Thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: 99% of BBC links repeatedly FAIL. 99% of all others succeed (two pcs numerous times).  Radioplayer say it is a BBC problem.  I might as well pray to Zeus! :-(